# What is the best practice to get database access in 'application\core' folder of code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have extended log file to save the logs to the database. So I need to access the database from 'application\core\MY_Log.php'
I have used the code as follows

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'core/Model.php');
$CI_Model = new CI_Model();
$CI_Model->db->where($where);
$CI_Model->db->order_by($orderBy);
$result  =   $CI_Model->db->get('table')->row_array();
```

but I'm getting an error like this

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function where() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\projfolder\application\core\MY_Log.php:

any comments on this will be a help

Comment: its getting error like this call to member function database on null

Comment: anybody, please help me with this.